# Need to cast self.view in UIViewController?

Tags: objective-c, ios, model-view-controller, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I've created a `UIViewController` which contains a view with a custom class that I've built.  I've connected the view to the File's Owner view outlet.  It renders properly and I don't have any real problems.  However, I want to call a method within my view from my view controller instance, say it's called `drawSomething`.  So within a method in my controller, I use:

```
[self.view drawSomething];
```

It works. But I get a pre-compiler warning because it appears to not know the methods within my custom view definition.  Is my approach wrong here?  I can create a local variable and cast it to make the warning go away obviously.  I've imported the view's header file, so that's not the issue.

I feel like I'm missing something trivial.

.h of my custom view contains:

```
-(void) drawSomething;
```

.m of my custom view contains:

```
-(void) drawSomething { <code> };
```

Comment: Can you post code your custom class? That would make everything easier :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`self.view` is basically a pointer to a `UIView` used as the main view for the view controller. Since your view is a custom class with custom methods, you need a cast to your custom class to call your custom methods:

```
[((MyCustomClass *)self.view) drawSomething];
```

Otherwise, you are calling `drawSomething` on a standard `UIView`, which does not exist.

Comment: Ok so this is the accepted/correct behavior then?  That's fine...I just thought that connecting it as an Outlet would handle that implicitly.

Comment: A cast is required.  It's a promise to the compiler that MyCustomClass really will work in this case.

Comment: Understood, it just seemed like something the compiler could figure out on its own, so it was unexpected.  Perfect, thanks guys.